# Add statistical information to the bottom of a graph

Tags: r, statistics, graphing

I am try to add statistical information (min, max, quartile values, mean, median etc) regarding a given distribution to the bottom a graph (histogram, time series plot) in R. 
I know the stats can be generated using the summary() function. However, does any know how to place such information at the bottom of a graph?

Its seems like it should be easy to do but I just can't find anything online regarding how  to do it. Is it even possible using R?

Any help would be gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one way. For some dummy data

```
set.seed(2)
dat <- rnorm(100, mean = 3, sd = 3)
```

compute the summary

```
sdat <- summary(dat)
```

We can then paste together the names of the summary statistics and their values using `paste()`, and `collapse` this to a single string

```
summStr <- paste(names(sdat), format(sdat, digits = 2), collapse = "; ")
```

Note that I format the values of the statistics to have just two significant digits using `format()`. This can be added to the plot say as a subtitle use the `title()` function

```
op <- par(mar = c(7,4,4,2) + 0.1)
hist(dat)
title(sub = summStr, line = 5.5)
par(op)
```

I push the subtitle down the plot a little bit via argument `line`.

[image: text added to a plot as a subtitle]

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a treat :)